# Mongoose foreing key model api populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models:

1. Articles

[image: article model]

2. Order

   [image]

For the article I wrote this model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const ArticlesSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    available_quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
 })

 const Articles = mongoose.model('articles', ArticlesSchema, 'articles');

 module.exports = Articles;
```

For the order I wrote this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const ArtIdSchema = new Schema({
    article_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'articles'},
    qty: {type: Number}
});

const OrdersSchema = new Schema({
  status: { type: String, required: true },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
  articles: [ArtIdSchema] 
})

const Orders = mongoose.model('orders', OrdersSchema, 'orders');

module.exports = Orders;
```

I need to populate "article_id" with the real Article so in my api.js I wrote this:

```
router.get('/orders/status/:status_id', (req, res, next) => {
    Orders.find({status: req.params.status_id}, 'status, articles')
    .populate('article_id')
    .exec((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(422).json({
            error: 'Your request could not be processed. Please try again.'
          });
        }
        res.status(200).json({
          data: data
        });
    });
});
```

But it's not working. I tried also replacing the `.populate('article_id')` with `.populate('articles')` but it's not working.

I'm new with Mongoose and I can't understand where it's wrong.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. I solved with this:

```
.populate('article.article_id')
```